# How to explode sentences with "。" but ignore the "。" in the double quotation marks

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am writing a program about getting the abstract of Chinese article. Firstly I have to explode each sentence with symbols like “。!?”.
In Chinese article, when referring other's word, they would use double quotation marks to mark the referred words, which may contain "。" but should not be exploded. For example, the following sentence:

他说：“今天天气很好。我很开心。”

It will be exploded into three sentences:

1. 他说：“今天天气很好
2. 我很开心
3. ”

The result is wrong, but how to solved it?
I have tried use regular expression, but I am not good at it, so could figure it out.
PS: I write this program with python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
import re

st=u'''\
今天天气很好。今天天气很好。bad? good! 今天天气很好。他说：“今天天气很好。我很开心。”
Sentence one. Sentence two! “Sentence three. Sentence four.” Sentence five?'''

pat=re.compile(r'(?:[^“。？！；~.]*?[?!。.；~])|(?:[^“。？！；~.]*?“[^”]*?”)')
print(pat.findall(st))
```

Prints:

```
['今天天气很好。', '今天天气很好。', 'bad?', ' good!', ' 今天天气很好。', 
 '他说：“今天天气很好。我很开心。”', '\nSentence one.', ' Sentence two!', 
 ' “Sentence three. Sentence four.”', ' Sentence five?']
```

And if you want the effect of a split (ie, won't include the delimiter), just move the capturing parenthesis and then print the match group:

```
pat=re.compile(r'([^“。？！；~.]*?)[?!。.；~]|([^“。？！；~.]*?“[^”]*?”)')
#  note the end paren:           ^
print([t[0] if t[0] else t[1] for t in pat.findall(st)])
```

Prints:

```
['今天天气很好', '今天天气很好', 'bad', ' good', ' 今天天气很好', 
 '他说：“今天天气很好。我很开心。”', '\nSentence one', ' Sentence two', 
 ' “Sentence three. Sentence four.”', ' Sentence five']
```

Or, use `re.split` with the same regex and then filter for True values:

```
print(list(filter(None, pat.split(st))))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.But if I set `st` as `'今天天气很好。今天天气很好。今天天气很好。他说：“今天天气很好。我很开心。”'`, the result is `['“今天天气很好。我很开心。”']`.Is there any better way?And I hope to split the sentences with "。？！；~" at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting, I’m matching all sentences using `re.findall`:

```
>>> s = '今天天气很好。今天天气很好。今天天气很好。他说：“今天天气很好。我很开心。”'
>>> re.findall('[^。“]+(?:。|“.*?”)', s)
['今天天气很好。', '今天天气很好。', '今天天气很好。', '他说：“今天天气很好。我很开心。”']
```

If you want to accept those other character as separators too, try this:

```
>>> re.findall('[^。？！；~“]+(?:[。？！；~]|“.*?”)', s)
```

Comment: Thank you!It works for symbol "。".Now I need to split the sentences with "？！；~" at the same time, could `re.split()` works?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'll assume the double quotes can't be nested. Then it's quite easy to do this without some complicated regular expression. You just split on `"`, and then you split the even parts on your punctuation.

```
>>> sentence = 'a: "b. c" and d. But e said: "f? g."'
>>> sentence.split('"')
['a: ', 'b. c', ' and d. But e said: ', 'f? g.', '']
```

You can see how the even parts are the ones not between quotes. We'll use `index % 2 == 1` to select the odd parts.

```
result = []
part = []
for i, p in enumerate(sentence.split('"')):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        part.append(p)
    else:
        parts = p.split('.')
        if len(parts) == 1:
            part.append(p)
        else:
            first, *rest, last = parts
            part.append(first)
            result.append('"'.join(part))
            result.extend(rest)
            part = [last]

result.append('"'.join(part))
```

Comment: After actually writing this out, I must admit that a regex might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this in two steps: first, find the dots inside the double quotes, and "protect" them (for example, replace them with a string like `$%$%$%$` that is unlikely to appear in a Chinese text.). Next, explode the strings as before. Finally, replace the `$%$%$%$` with a dot again.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work:

```
$str = '他说：“今天天气很好。我很开心。”';
print_r( preg_split('/(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)。/u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) );
```

This makes sure that `。` is matched only when outside double quotes.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 他说：“今天天气很好
    [1] => 我很开心
    [2] => ”
)
```

Comment: That's what he did not want. He wanted the punctuation between quotes to be "escaped" from the splitting.

Comment: And although the OP uses the term `explode` - it is tagged for python-3.x and the OP says they're writing it uses Python3...